# ERROR:child_thread_impl.cc(762)] Request for unknown Channel-associated interface: ui::mojom::GpuMain

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I try to use selenium(latest version, chrome version  58) with `org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver`. This class has documentation which appears in eclipse. It includes simple test:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class ChromeTest extends TestCase {

    private static ChromeDriverService service;
    private WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void createAndStartService() {
        service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
                .usingDriverExecutable(new File("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"))
                .usingAnyFreePort().build();
        try {
            service.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("service didn't start");
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void createAndStopService() {
        service.stop();
    }

    @Before
    public void createDriver() {
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(service.getUrl(), capabilities);
    }

    @After
    public void quitDriver() {
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGoogleSearch() {
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        searchBox.sendKeys("webdriver");
        // searchBox.quit();
        assertEquals("webdriver - Google Search", driver.getTitle());
    }
}
```

When I run it, new google chrome window appears on desktop. And in eclipse console I see:

```
ERROR:child_thread_impl.cc(762)] Request for unknown Channel-associated interface: ui::mojom::GpuMain
```

I tried to solve it by using :

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
```

But it didn't help. I still have the same error.

After I did debug I see that this error message appears on console when native method `java.lang.Thread.start0()` is called. Inside `java.lang.Thread.start` method there is call to native `start0()`.

What is wrong with my comp(windows 7)?

How to solve this ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

I misunderstood method `usingDriverExecutable` of `ChromeDriverService.Builder()`.
This method expects path to `chromedriver.exe` file but I set path to `chrome.exe`. Correct code is:

```
@BeforeClass
    public static void createAndStartService() {
        service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
                .usingDriverExecutable(new File("D:\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe"))
                .withVerbose(false).usingAnyFreePort().build();
        try {
            service.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("service didn't start");
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

You can also set it with `webdriver.chrome.driver` system  property:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
```

To download latest `chromedriver.exe` go to https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads. From this page they send you to https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.29/.