# How to fix Request for unknown Channel-associated interface: ui::mojom::GpuMain?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have already posted question regarding my problem at [ERROR:child_thread_impl.cc(762)] Request for unknown Channel-associated interface: ui::mojom::GpuMain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43761079/errorchild-thread-impl-cc762-request-for-unknown-channel-associated-interfac).

Thanks if you look there.

On internet I have found these solutions:

1. Use `--disable-gpu` option. How to use it?
2. What means

> re-downloading Chromedriver at
>   https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=‌​2.28/

How to use this driver?

Answer (score 0):

its enough to download and add it to your PATH variable